# How to express the idea of an object "stripped" of everything but the object itself, e.g. a stripped van or bed

Tags: english-to-german, idiomaticity, english

I'm a native german speaker, but I'm struggling to find a usable translation for "stripped van".  **Is there german idiom similiar to the english stripped**, in the sense of

> strip
>
> past tense: stripped; past participle: stripped
>
> 1. remove all coverings from. "they stripped the bed"
> 2. leave bare of accessories or fittings. "thieves stripped the room of luggage"

**Some background**: I am planning on buying a van and remodelling it completely, so that I can live the "van life" in this van, departing from Germany, and likely heading to Morocco and hopefully later Saudi Arabia, India, etc.

For this, I am searching for a stripped van on various online portals here in Germany, but feel I am hindered in this search by the fact that I don't know how to express the idea of a stripped van in german.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail, what a "stripped van" is? What exactly does it not have? No radio? No furniture? That will help us help you better.

Comment: What keywords did you try that did not give you the desired success?

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and it's a little unclear to me too. When I've heard it used in reference to a vehicle, "stripped" means everything of value and not actually welded to the frame has been removed: radio, seats, tires, carburetor, head and tail lights etc., even the motor, doors and windshield if the "stripper" as the time and energy. In other words a "stripped" vehicle would not be drivable at all, much less capable of a trip to another continent.

Comment: I have closed the question for now, as it lacks a more detailed description of what exactly is the thing you are looking for. Please edit your question and add the missing information. I will be happy to reopen the question then. Just mark me in a comment once it is done.

Comment: @Jonathan I see absolutely nothing unclear in this question. It is explained by OP if it makes sense to us, how they want to conduct their van-travels or not is irrelevant to the question that is clearly stated.

Comment: @infinitezero Could you give an explanation of the term "stripped van"? What is stripped off? "everything that is not welded to the frame", as RDBury reckons? Or just the parts that are not necessary for driving? Or just some specific parts? The answer to the question depends heavily on this definition, I fear. But of course, the goal here is to get this question opened and answered. So I am happy to get clarification from you, and would like to encourage you to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not aware of different verbs for different stages of stripping/gutting. To me there's only "ausschlachten". I.e. "komplett ausgeschlachtet" would correspond to RDBury's intuition, while "Innenraum ausgeschlachtet" would probably be more likely what OP has in mind. But if there are indeed different words for this, then I'll gladly admit to be mistaken and learn something new :)